# How can I ensure images are displayed with a uniform size in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am building an About page which will contain headshots of people. I have photos of each of the people, but the photos are in different sizes. I want the website to contain rounded photos that are of a uniform size. The code I have so far is shown below, but the images on the website are not of uniform size.

```
img-fluid rounded-circle mb-3
```

Comment: I will just crop and resize the source images to be same sizes before putting them on the website. I mean, you can definitely set a fixed width and height of the thumbnail container and either make the source images to be the container background or put the source image within the container, but if the source image is too small and the container is too big, when you make the image 100% width, it will look fuzzy. I wrote https://wongsbuildingsupply.com/ and I have the Crop & resize feature for the admins before they publish images to public.

Comment: Always using the images with the same dimensions is the best practice. The ways you can achieve it are by placing all the images with same height and width, cropping is the one phase(as mentioned by @DavidLiang) and if the image width is too large and the container is small that will compress the image to fit in the container which looks awkward or you need to position the images one by one which will add a few lines of CSS code, but that will do.

Comment: Getting only the headshots might be difficult to achieve with images of different aspect ratios. It would have been simgle for other placeholding images.